# Query to display both max value and the column that relates to the max value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to get the product name and the total qty of that product ordered to date to be displayed side by side for the product that has the maximum total order quantity.

The data comes from two tables (1) Sales_order and (2) Products

Sales order table structure:
ID (INT)
product (INT)
quantity_ordered(INT)
Products table structure:
Product_code (INT)
Product_line (Varchar(20))
They are linked by Products.Product_code ->> Sales_order.product

My query was:

```
 select x.product_line, x.TotalQty from     
    ( select P. Product_line,sum(S.quantity_ordered) as TotalQty        
      from sales_order S        
      join products P on S.product = P.product_code         
      group by P. Product_line
     order by TotalQty desc     
    ) x 
 where x.TotalQty = select max(x.TotalQty) from x
```

The inner query produced the following result:

```
product_line    TotalQty
"Classic Cars"  33992
"Vintage Cars"  21069
"Motorcycles"   11663
```

but once I put the outer query and the 'where' clause, I get the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select" LINE 8: where x.TotalQty =
> select max(x.TotalQty) from x

I also tried :

```
where x.TotalQty = (select max(x.TotalQty) from x)
```

by putting parentheses around the last select, but this gave an error that relation x does not exist.

I am new to SQL and can't figure out what I am doing wrong and how to correct it. (The requirement is not to "find the answer" like by using order-by in descending order and picking the first item. I am supposed to write code to display both the product_line and the TotalQty side by side for only the max value, or the one that exactly matches the average of all order quantities ...etc.).

Comment: provide the structures please

Comment: Get rid of the outer query and add `limit 1` to the query.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator: You really could not understand this simple question without me providing a structure of its two little tables, that you had to give me a negative score? I am a beginner, and even I would have no problems understanding this question without me giving lengthy explanations about its structure. Those who have the intention of helping others have answered this question without getting baffled and they had no problem understanding my question. Please do not be in such a hurry to hurt others' ratings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CTE will be a better a choice, as you can use the CTE as basis for your queries.

```
CREATE tABLe sales_order(quantity_ordered int, product int)
```

```
CREATE tABLe products (Product_line varchar(10),product_code int)
```

```
WITH CTE AS (select P. Product_line,sum(S.quantity_ordered) as TotalQty        
      from sales_order S        
      join products P on S.product = P.product_code         
      group by P. Product_line
     order by TotalQty desc)
 select x.product_line, x.TotalQty from     
    CTE x
 where x.TotalQty = (select max(TotalQty) from CTE)
```

| product_line | totalqty |
| --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UI54pVig)

Comment: while your solution works perfectly, I will be thankful if you could point out which portion of the query that I wrote is wrong, so I understand in principle and would not make the same error in other situations.

Comment: Sql does"t know x the table for your max funtion, you need to repeat the complete  suvquery or use a cte, because for rhe query the cte ecists like any other table in that database. Some concepts are difficult  to grap at the begining